# How do I change the resizing behavior of an image that is set to cover?

Tags: css

I'm trying to get an element to resize to the top when the viewport gets smaller

```
    div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* the ideal scenario would be that the bottom of the image stays aligned to the bottom, then when resized, everything would get pushed to the top instead */

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/* thanks in advance  */
```

https://jsfiddle.net/37xf9Lab

Comment: I consider specifying size of all elements with a div tag a bad practice, use class instead.

Comment: object-position:top ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif object-position: bottom works fine, for what ever reason I can't get this to work in Elementor :\